# Null exception in httprequest

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to get values form mysql(xampp) database but its not working 
my database name is meeting_planner and table name is participant

```
try {

                HttpPost httppost;

                HttpClient httpclient;

                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                httppost = new HttpPost(

                "http://10.10.10.159/my_folder_inside_htdocs/getdata.php");

                System.out.println("after url");

                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

                System.out.println("after response handler");

                 final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost,

                        responseHandler);




                 System.out.println("the response is "+response);

                 Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();

            }
```

getdata.php code is here

```
<?php

     mysql_connect("localhost","admin","admin"); // host, username, password...

   mysql_select_db("meeting_planner"); // db name...


    $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM participant");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))

            $json_output[]=$row;

          print(json_encode($json_output));

    mysql_close();

?>
```

the response variable is null in result of System.out.println("response"+response);
log cat is here

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)

at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)

at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)

at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)

at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)

at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)

at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)

at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)

at
```

org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOpera

tor.java:144)

```
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)

at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)

at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)

at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)

at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:653)

at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)

at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)

at com.example.androidmeetingplanner.Invite.addListenerOnButton(Invite.java:130)

at com.example.androidmeetingplanner.Invite.onCreate(Invite.java:39)

at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)

at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)

at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: Sadia, please post your error here. I think you doing wrong call request.

Comment: post full logcat error message

Comment: yet another `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` .... before asking question you should do at least minimal effort and do some research(googling) on your own !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting NetworkOnMainThreadException. please use AsyncTask to make HttpRequest like the following:

```
    private class HttpGetter extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(URL... urls) {
                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost= new HttpPost(          "http://10.10.10.159/my_folder_inside_htdocs/getdata.php");
                    System.out.println("after url");
                    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                    System.out.println("after response handler");
                    String response = httpclient.execute(httppost,responseHandler);
                    System.out.println("the response is "+response);
                    Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }   
            return null; 
        }
}
```

And in your activity write the following code to execute it

```
    HttpGetter getter = new HttpGetter();
    getter.execute(null,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException said that you call request in GUI thread. You should do all operations with network in another thread.

For example, you can add this code into AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this reference: [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception) . Android cannot let you make an http request on main Thread, you should make a request on different thread